# Using 1000 separator when writing Excel

Tags: excel, separator

How to use 1000 separator when writing Numbers to Excel Sheet with java? Typical Decimal Formatter forces the double value to String. I want the value to be in format 000 (space) 000,00

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the field's number format. see the API's. The separator is a display option, not a modification of the 'numeric value'.

Comment: So how do I use it? Setting cellview?

Comment: @jaana: sorry, my experience with writing excel-files is with perl (on solaris boxes), so I have 'only' rather generic sense advice, that you probably tried already.  What does the JavaAPI documentation (and google) say about that function? Did you try handcrafting a pattern in Excel and assigning that?